# kubernetes with Nginx and SSL

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am trying to configure Nginx with Kubernetes and have done it. I was trying to implement the same with SSL but unable to do so as most of the help I see is only for the ingress controller.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Need a bit more info here.When you say nginx with kubernetes are you running a container with nginx and in the nginx.conf file you are handling all your traffic.Nginx can also be configured as HTTPS.
But the better way is to use an ingress resource with an nginx ingress controller in kubernetes

Comment: Can you post more details?

Comment: Thanks Rico and Avinash. i got the answer and was able to achieve same and yes its true that ingress controller is better way for SSL.